# pvcreate error on partition

Tags: partition, devices, fdisk

I can't create this partition, I'm getting this error shown below:

> Device /dev/mapper/vg_paperino-lv_rootp1 not found (or ignored by filtering)

Below are the steps that I'm doing on CentOS:

```
[root@pippo ~]# fdisk /dev/mapper/vg_paperino-lv_root

WARNING: DOS-compatible mode is deprecated. It's strongly recommended to
         switch off the mode (command 'c') and change display units to
         sectors (command 'u').

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_paperino-lv_root: 18.8 GB, 18832424960 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2289 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xdb344dbe

                          Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/vg_paperino-lv_rootp1               1           3       24066   83  Linux
Command (m for help): q
[root@pippo ~]# pvcreate /dev/mapper/vg_paperino-lv_rootp1
Device /dev/mapper/vg_paperino-lv_rootp1 not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's not a normal partition. It's created by pvcreate after you've assigned some either whole disks or partitions from a disk to a logical volume in LVM.

Say you have 2 partitions, /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1.

First you label them as LVM partitions:

```
pvcreate /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

Then add them to a volume group:

```
vgcreate new_vol_group /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
```

You can confirm this with the `vgs` command:

```
# vgs
  VG            #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  new_vol_group   2   0   0 wz--n- 51.45G 51.45G
```

Then create the logical volume:

```
lvcreate -L2G -n new_logical_volume new_vol_group
  Logical volume "new_logical_volume" created
```

Then create a file system on the logical volume:

```
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/new_vol_group/new_logical_volume
```

Then mount it:

```
mount /dev/new_vol_group/new_logical_volume /mnt
```

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense. You can't fdisk the LVM volumes, they aren't MBR partitions. Your use of `fdisk` seems wrong to me here. Can you please expand your question with exactly what you're trying to do? Please give each step! You could run `fdisk` on the partitions added to the LVM for example. They should be showing up as "8e - Linux LVM" partitions.

Comment: http://www.mondoinformatico.info/logical-volume-manager-lvm-su-linux-tutorial-passo-passo_post-7851.html


pvcreate /dev/sda2p1
Device /dev/sda2p1 not found (or ignored by filtering).


"stackexchange.com" can not do more than write so many characters, it does not do ...

Comment: I looked through the tutorial you posted. I don't mean this is a mean spirited way, but you must not be following the directions 8-). Are you literally trying to do a `pvcreate /dev/sda2p1`? What Linux distro is this? The Linux kernel usually shows the partitions as `/dev/sda1`, the whole disk is `/dev/sda`, for example.

Comment: Centos 6.2, Now I'm doing the download of centos 6.4

Comment: Same OSes that I've got here. Are you trying to do a `pvcreate /dev/sda2p1`?

Comment: I'm not seeing any changes in the steps, I think you're doing something incorrectly. Here's a tutorial for CentOS6, same steps as I've outlined: http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=lvm

Comment: yes he is, let's see if installing the 6.4 disappears ...

Comment: I'll know after I installed centos 6.4, thanks for your great link ....OpenAm you know?

Comment: You CAN create (and transparently use!) partition tables on LVs (see `kpartx`). Whether (and when) that makes sense is a completely different question. At any rate this adds a certain amount of "fun" to system administration... Of course, I agree that in this case it's a misunderstanding.

Comment: I figured you could but we could also shoot ourselves in the head with a gun but we definitely don't want to do that 8-). Best to stay with norms unless you REALLY know what you're doing.

Comment: I solved the problem, before running "pvcreate" I had to do a reboot the server ..... ops ops ;) ;)

Comment: Glad you solved your issue.